# MySQL Query tableA order by if has post in tableB with date of this month

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables.

I want to make a query on tableA and order by tableB.

This is an accounting system.

TableA contains customers. TableB contains Payments made by customers.

I want to `select *` from TableA order by where he has a payment in TableB with a Date of this month first, then the rest with no payments.

Comment: You can use functions and expressions in your ORDER BY clause, like in ORDER BY IF(b.payment = now(), 0, 1). For more help, show sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
    ON TableB.customer_id = TableA.customer_id
ORDER BY COALESCE(TableB.payDate, '1900-01-01') DESC
```

Comment: Probably not what the OP wants since this will return multiple rows for customers who have made more than 1 past payment.

Answer (score 0):

You can outer join the two tables, group by the identifying info in TableA, and order by the max payment date in TableB, like this:

```
select customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, 
  max(payment.payment_date)
from customer
  left outer join payment on payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id
group by customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name
order by max(payment.payment_date) desc
```